# Query Data from multiple sql tables

Tags: mysql, node.js

[image]

I have an ERD above. I want to get the price of the room based on channel and also the status (isInvisible) of the hotel that owns the room mentioned.

Also a RESTful-API endpoint for that, I tried many times on this assignment and can't get it right as I use Nodejs to write an API GET /api/${roomId}/price but the query doesn't work:

```
SELECT RoomPrice.price, Status.isInvisible
FROM RoomPrice
INNER JOIN Status
ON (RoomPrice.RoomID = Room.Id AND RoomPrice.ChannelID = ChannelId)
AND (Status.HotelID = Hotels.ID AND Status.ChannelID = ChannelID)
```

I use query below to create my database in WorkBench:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `address`;

CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   FOREIGN KEY(hotel_id) REFERENCES hotels(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `address` (`hotel_id`, `address`) 
VALUES 
(1, '7008 Lynch Centers Apt. 596\nLysannemouth, RI 43355'),
(2, '04795 Stanley Mount Apt. 114\nDorrisborough, DC 38070-3542'),
(1, '24586 Eliseo Haven Suite 045\nKossville, WY 17890-7936'),
(2, '639 Toy Corners\nBashirianfort, CA 08964-7258');



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `channels`;

CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `channels` (`id`, `url`, `name`) 
VALUES 
(1, 'http://www.beahan.com/', 'quod'),
(2, 'http://www.douglas.com/', 'sit');



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hotels`;

CREATE TABLE `hotels` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `hotels` (`id`, `name`) 
VALUES 
(1, 'illum'),
(2, 'aliquid');
    



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `rooms`;

CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY(hotel_id) REFERENCES hotels(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `rooms` (`id`, `hotel_id`, `name`) 
VALUES 
(1, 1, 'vel'),
(2, 2, 'fugit'),
(3, 1, 'doloribus'),
(4, 2, 'ut'),
(5, 1, 'et');



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `room_prices`;

CREATE TABLE `room_prices` (
  `room_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (room_id, channel_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(room_id) REFERENCES rooms(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(channel_id) REFERENCES channels(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `room_prices` (`room_id`, `channel_id`, `price`) 
VALUES 
(1, 1, '50687.86'),
(1, 2, '6687.86'),
(2, 1, '10687.86'),
(2, 2, '274739.20'),
(3, 1, '3828.63'),
(3, 2, '12525.86'),
(4, 1, '2623587.86'),
(4, 2, '125151.00'),
(5, 1, '2358704.85'),
(5, 2, '7347473.86');
    


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `status`;

CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `hotel_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `isInvisible` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (hotel_id, channel_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(hotel_id) REFERENCES hotels(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(channel_id) REFERENCES channels(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `status` (`hotel_id`, `channel_id`, `isInvisible`) 
VALUES 
(1, 1, false),
(2, 1, true),
(1, 2, true),
(2, 2, true);
```

I want that once I query to search for the price of roomId (i.e 1) it returns 2 rows (as the mock data only have 2 rows in channels table) that show:

```
room_id  channel_id  price     isInvisible
1        1           xxxx.xx   0
1        2           xxxx.xx   1
```

At this moment, I use the query as DRapp help

```
    SELECT 
      rp.room_id,
      rp.channel_id,
      rp.price,
      s.isInvisible
   FROM 
      room_prices rp
      JOIN status s
        ON (rp.channel_id = s.channel_id)
        JOIN rooms r
            ON (rp.room_id = r.id)
            JOIN hotels h
                ON (r.hotel_id = h.id)
      WHERE rp.room_id = 1
```

It returns 4 rows (instead of 2 rows as expected)

```
room_id  channel_id  price     isInvisible
1        1           xxxx.xx   0
1        2           xxxx.xx   1
1        1           xxxx.xx   1
1        2           xxxx.xx   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify each of the relations as your ERD shows.  Each table is joined to its respective context.  Dont jump/skip.  The only time you can in this scenario is to skip through the channels since the RoomPrice and Status table EACH have a "ChannelId" to qualify the join

```
SELECT 
      rp.price,
      s.isInvisible
   FROM 
      Room_Prices rp
         JOIN Rooms r
            on rp.room_id = r.id
               JOIN Status s
                  ON rp.Channel_ID = s.Channel_Id
                  AND r.hotel_id = s.hotel_id
   WHERE
        rp.room_id = 1
```

I had to revise the query.  I looked deeper and noticed your CHANNEL table ALSO had the Hotel, so I had to go from the room prices to the room table.  From the room table, I can get the hotel.  Now that I have the channel from room prices, AND the hotel ID from the rooms table.  So NOW I join to the status table on BOTH columns getting the expected single row per room you are expecting.

Comment: https://products.groupdocs.app/viewer/view?file=8bb56066-d113-4055-ada6-6509fe2a01f0/hotels-room-booking.sql

I build my db as the sql file with the url then apply your script and it act a little bit weird as if I run the query with rp.room_id = 1, it should return 2 rows that show price of room 1 on channel_id: 1, isInvisible; and price of room 1 on channe_id:2, isInvisible. But it return multiple rows of room 1 on channel 1 and multiple rows of room 1 on channel 2

Comment: The data 5 rows of data on room 1 channel 1 is correct as it's 0, after that the 5 rows on room 1 channel 2 is also correct, but after that the 5 rows next have room 1 channel 1 has isInvisible 1 (true), which is not correct anymore

Comment: @SyQuoc, I would EDIT your existing post.  Show SAMPLE Data of what you have in each respective table, even if only 3-10 records to get the point across.  Then show what you EXPECT the return results to be.  Again, EDIT your existing post with details and save it.

Comment: I editted on my existing post and also a link to sql file that used to create my database accordingly to the ERD. I appreciate your help

Comment: @SyQuoc, dont post links to documents.  Especially ones people may not trust (I would not).  Do a copy-paste in your actual post.  Its a pain in case future the linked documents are gone.  Strip out just what you need to, to get the point and sample data across to complete the post.

Comment: OKay, I post the query to create the database instead of the link

Comment: @SyQuoc, revised query in my answer.  Needed BOTH columns of hotel AND channel for uniqueness returned.